# How to keep get parameters upon form submition

Tags: html, web

The current url is:
http://localhost:8000/?sort=age
and I have a filter in the page.

```
<form method="GET">
Filter By Name:<input name="filter" id="filter" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

when the filter is applied, I expect the url to become:
http://localhost:8000/?sort=age&filter=maria
but it changes the url to:
http://localhost:8000/?filter=maria

Is there a way to keep the current parameters?

Comment: The current url is:`http://localhost:8000/?sort=age `, but in your form there is no `sort`.Where is `sort=age`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form submissions only add query parameters that are included in the form itself, they don't consider parameters already present in the URL/post or tags outside the form in question. Look at the [relevant page in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13) for the exact details on what gets submitted.

On how to preserve them, the easiest method would be the server to include extra hidden inputs within the form with the current parameters to be preserved:

```
<form method="GET">
Filter By Name:<input name="filter" id="filter" type="text"/>
<input type="hidden" name="sort" value="age"/>
<input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

A second option would be to use Javascript. The submit button can invoke some script that can scan the current URL and add the extra parameters. Not exactly trivial, so I would leave it as a second option if more control is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I did it in the backend with the hidden input. It was easier than javscript approach as you said.